# Pendrive is not copying anything

Tags: mount, fstab

I am using ubntu-18.04 lts.Recently there was some problem with my pendrive(it was showing very less memory though it contained no files!) so, I formatted it using gparted but now I followed that mount point is changed and also I can't copy anything to pendrive .
my /etc/fstab file detail:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=a15e2f3d-2f50-41c6-8e07-7bf861329f99 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=68747df0-f007-40b7-a5f1-89cb232c6337 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=995626c2-17db-41c3-a3c5-95aa6a732a4e none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Please help me out.

Comment: If you format (or mkfs) a device, the UUID will change (unless you specifically told it to use the UUID previously used).  I' suggest checking the UUID matches the formatted device (use `blkid` or like tool to list block devices detail)

Comment: I think i have blkid preinstalled but when i use blkid command output gives nothing !  Also I tried installing lsblk but it's not available .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this forum :

When you attach your USB key to your laptop:

1. run sudo -i (so that you won't type your password all the time)
2. run df -Th(to see where your USB stick is mounted)
3. unmount your USB stick
4. run dosfsck on the device you saw from your previous command.
   Example: dosfsck /dev/sdc1
5. remove and reattach your USB stick

Problem should be solved now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)